# How to implement a timetable in Android

Tags: android, layout, android-tablelayout, timetable

I know this sort of question has been asked a few times now but all threads I read didn't really help me out with this specific problem, so here's the thing:

For our IT lesson at school, we have to develop our own app. Unlike my fellows, I've already had some experience with developing android apps but this problem overwhelmed me... :(

My idea was to create a student's management app to keep track of the timetable, upcoming exams and so on...

But I got stuck at the timetable beacause I don't know how to realize those "lesson placeholder thingies" (don't know how to name 'em :D).

Just look at my source code and you'll understand:

section_table.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/top_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spaceView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.16" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/monday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
        android:text="@string/monday" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tuesday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
        android:text="@string/tuesday" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wednesday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
        android:text="@string/wednesday" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thursday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
        android:text="@string/thursday" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
        android:text="@string/friday" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="1" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="2" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="3" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="4" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="5" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="6" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="7" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="8" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="9" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="10" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow11"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="11" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow12"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="12" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow13"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="13" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow14"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="14" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow15"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="15" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow16"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="16" />
</TableRow>
```

My problem is that I don't know whether to use buttons, textviews, views, etc... 
Using a button forced the other tablerows to get smaller and unreadable... :(

Please help, thank you guys very much in advance! :)

Comment: A picture would help. I mean, what do you want to achieve? What should be in the table and how should it look like?

Comment: I really thank you for trying to help me, but I've finally managed it!!! I simply added buttons with attributes "fill_parent" in height, so that they fit...

Comment: General advice - use "match_parent" instead of "fill_parent". The latter has been deprecated by Google.

Comment: thank you - I've applied your advice :))